# Remove a object from a JSON object list

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML code:

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in objects">{{obj.name}} <a ng-click="remove($index)">x</a></li>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
    $scope.objects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
    "0": { "name": "name1" },
    "1": { "name": "name2" }
}
```

When `remove()` is called, I get `TypeError: $scope.objects.splice is not a function`, here I know `$scope.objects` is not an array and so `splice()` will not work.

Is there any method to remove the selected index??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `delete $scope.objects[index]`

Comment: Need more code for $scope creation

Comment: The solution by @adeneo worked, but while removing there seems to be another issue, http://jsfiddle.net/salvadorcs/9d8ztbpL/

Comment: when i remove name2 and then name1 it works fine, but the other way the name2 is not removed

Comment: the indexes of $scope.objects remains same after calling remove()

Comment: The indexes won't change unless you manually update them, because you are using an object as an array, you would need to `delete` every property after the removed index and then add the properties back with their property name as the new index rather than the old. The [docs for `ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) give several options for tracking the collection items. Can you add a unique identifier to the JSON output and remove using that instead?

Comment: got that @Sean updated then with "track by $index" in ng-repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a json object and not an array you can use ng-repeat like this

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in objects">{{value.name}} <a ng-click="remove(key)">x</a></li>
```

So that the remove method can delete current list element by key:

```
$scope.remove = function(key) {
     delete $scope.objects[key];
}
```

Here's a [plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXvqyr).

$index is quite confusing in cases like this as it is dynamic whereas the keys are not.